# Unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522913

Tags: centos, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to run Protractor tests on centOS with headless chrome.
When I run the tests with "protractor conf.js" the system throws strange error:

```
[root@stage conf]# protractor conf.js
[10:17:16] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[10:17:16] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[10:18:18] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522913 (36222509aa6e819815938cbf2709b4849735537c),platform=Linux 3.10.0-6                                93.5.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.12 seconds
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
System info: host: 'stage', ip: '10.10.19.203', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-693                                .5.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[10:18:18] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522913 (36222509aa6e819815938cbf2709b4849735537c),platform=Linux 3.10.0-6                                93.5.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.12 seconds
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
System info: host: 'stage', ip: '10.10.19.203', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-693                                .5.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at WebDriverError (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/err                                or.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:                                13)
    at doSend.then.response (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:4                                41:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriv                                er.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:7                                61:15)
    at createDriver (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:626:16)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[10:18:18] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

I am using: 
Chromedriver v 2.34.522913,
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core), 
Protractor Version 5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this might be CentosOS issue with chrome.
If i would be you - i would check if chrome is actually installed normally: https://www.tecmint.com/install-google-chrome-on-redhat-centos-fedora-linux/

And also you might consider using Chromium instead Chrome, since i heard that Chrome might not work well on CentosOS:
https://www.hiroom2.com/2017/08/11/centos-7-chromium-en/
Chromedriver would be same for Chrome and Chromium

Another option might be to run Chrome in Docker Container